# Generic way to download DNS Blacklist

Tags: rbl

I am looking for a generic way to download (multiple) DNS blacklists. The reason is that I would like to cache them locally for faster lookup. The lookup is not for an MXer, but for a log analysis tool. This tool will dedup IPs, so I will lookup each IP only once - thus I asume that DNS caching won't help much.

Some blacklists offer downloading, but that seems to be specific to the list. Of course I could just query each blacklist for all possible IPv4 addresses and use the results to build a unified local list - however that seems awefully inefficient, and will probably get me on some other blacklist :)

So is there a generic method for dns blacklist download?

Comment: dns caching does help much. and almost all logalanyzer have its own dns cache file.

Comment: Try to download from [here](http://urlblacklist.com/?sec=download) it may help !

Comment: I was aware of that site - I was looking for a generic way to download lists that do not feature an explicit "download" link.

Comment: @IporSircer: If you dedup IPs, how are DNS caches supposed to help?